# Disable JQuery Ui tabs keyboard navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I am trying to disable the Keyboard navigation for JQuery Tabs on my site.

I have tried all the things listed in this question: [Prevent default jquery-ui tab behaviour when using keyboard navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15896437/prevent-default-jquery-ui-tab-behaviour-when-using-keyboard-navigation)

but to no avail.

**My current code is** (yes it looks nooby but i'm desperate, i'm also a noob at JS )

```
$.widget( ".wpb_tabs, .wpb_tab, .wpb_tab a, .wpb_tour_tabs_wrapper", $.ui.tabs, {
options: {
  keyboard: true
},
_tabKeydown: function(e) {
  if(this.options.keyboard) {
    this._super( '_tabKeydown' );
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
});

jQuery('.wpb_tabs, .wpb_tab, .wpb_tab a, .wpb_tour_tabs_wrapper').tabs({
activate: function(e, ui) {
e.currentTarget.blur();
}
});
```

**My Website is** (page im refering to): http://safercareltd.com/care-and-advice/

**Link to JS that calls tabs functions:** http://safercareltd.com/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/js/js_composer_front.js

Any help as to what i am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to unbind the keydown event on the li.

```js
$( ".selector" ).tabs().find('.ui-tabs-nav li').off('keydown')
```

Comment: For me worked: `$(".ui-tabs-tab,.ui-tabs-panel").off("keydown");`

Answer (score 1):

Just had to do this myself.  This is what worked for me:

```
$.widget("ui.tabs", $.ui.tabs, {
    _tabKeydown: function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode !== 38 && event.keyCode !== 40) {
            this._super(event);
        }
    }
});
```

You can substitute any combination of keys using event.keyCode and even make it customizable with something like:

```
$.widget("ui.tabs", $.ui.tabs, {
    options: {
        overrideKeyCodes: [],
    },
    _tabKeydown: function (event) {
        var isOverride = false;
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(this.options.overrideKeyCodes) === '[object Array]') {
            for (i = 0; i < this.options.overrideKeyCodes.length; i++) {
                if (event.keyCode === this.options.overrideKeyCodes[i]) {
                    isOverride = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!isOverride) {
            this._super(event);
        }
    }
});

$('#MyTabs').tabs({ overrideKeyCodes: [ 38, 40 ] });
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a jsfiddle. It's a workaround for what you are doing. Here is the link:http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/15/

Modification:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        ui.newTab.blur();
    },
});
$('#tabs a').click(function () {
    $(this).blur();
});
```

According to your html structure:

```
    $('.wpb_wrapper').tabs({
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        ui.newTab.blur();
    },
    });
   $('.wpb_tabs_nav a').click(function () {
      $(this).blur();
  });
```

Here is another fiddle with your site content and tabs: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/17/

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. 
Here is what i have `$('.wpb_tabs').tabs({
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        ui.newTab.blur();
    },
});
$('.wpb_tabs .wpb_tab').click(function () {
    $(this).blur();
});`

Comment: It will work if you bind the click event on the anchors.
 '$('.wpb_wrapper').tabs({ activate: function (event, ui) { ui.newTab.blur(); }, }); $('.wpb_tabs_nav a').click(function () { $(this).blur(); });'

Comment: stll no luck. If you look at (http://safercareltd.com/care-and-advice/) youu'll see what i mean. The tabs still stay focused

Comment: @WednesdayMan: show your javascript code in a jsfiddle.

Comment: If you look at the second fiddle which I included in the answer, the above code seems to work. JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/17/

Comment: here is the code in fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ZN9JA/2/ ...

It has something todo with the included js library **js_composer_front.js**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51303/discussion-between-wednesday-man-and-kamlesh-kushwaha)